# Unity 3D versus Gnome Shell

Tags: unity, gnome

Which one is better?

Which one is efficient?

Which one is mature?

Which one is hotter?

Who has compared both for pros and cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions aren't all answerable (eg 'better' is entirely opinion - you would need to ask 'better for purpose X') but what can be said is:

- Unity 3D provides a 3D desktop, [with Gnome as a fallback](http://digitizor.com/2011/01/18/no-unity-2d-natty/) for computers that can't run Unity 3d
- Gnome is much more mature
- Unity 3D requires far greater resources, but this doesn't imply greater or lesser efficiency - it does a lot more, visually.
- Hotter?? What do you mean? Is this similar to better?
- The folks at Ubuntuforums seem to have done some comparitive testing, but I don't see any major results out yet

I would advise updating your question to give your needs, then it may be easier to provide comments about which is better for those needs.

Comment: Neither Unity nor **GNOME Shell** can be considered mature. Both haven't yet been part of a release of a major distribution, so there haven't been "real world" testing by a larger user base.

Comment: @htorque - ooh - good point, sorry, I misread that